# How do I update only one specific application

Tags: updates, update-manager, chromium

I have chromium installed. I want to update it and only it. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Will actually perform an update instead of an install.

Keep in mind that changing from one version of an package to another is still considered an "install" in dpkg terms. It's only us humans that see it as an update.

As EliahKagan has pointed out, updating chromium will also update its dependencies, where needed.

Comment: `chromium-browser`

Comment: This answers half the question. The OP also wants to know how to prevent all other applications from updating.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 The question is asking how to update a single application without updating others. I think this answers that. (I think the material your answer is relevant and should stay--or be expanded--though.) **coteyr**: `apt-get install` resolves dependencies, so if another package (such as `chromium-browser-l10n`) has to be upgraded in order to upgrade `chromium-browser`, that will happen. But this is probably what the OP wants.

Comment: @EliahKagan That is certainly valid info, but you can not install chromium-browser without it's dependencies, nor could you update it, regardless of what method you used (even dpkg, or standalone binary distro). Eliah is correct though. It will update it's dependencies while updating chromium. If you do not want to update one of it's dependencies then it's better to just not update chromium. Forcing an install/update without dependencies will leave you with a broken system/app 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: @coteyr `apt-get install` will often *not* upgrade dependencies. It does so when the new version of the package being "`install`"ed requires a newer version of the dependency than is currently present. Old versions of packages that continue satisfying dependencies for the new version don't get upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

A (somewhat cumbersome) way to do this would be to have the Update Manager set so updates are not installed automatically, and then uncheck every listed package in the available updates except for Chromium.

Just keep in mind that updates in stable Ubuntu releases are provided to correct stability and security bugs - by not installing them, your system could be less stable or secure than it could be.